# sorting java task by user-entered dates

Tags: java, sorting

I'm creating a tasks list in java and want to be able to sort my data by user-entered due dates.  Below is what I have so far.  For the Case 3 of the switch statement I want to sort by the variable dueDate in case 2: how could I access this?  Could I use collection.sort for a date?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static String fileName = "/Users/Desktop/tasklistjava/src/javatask.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int menuItem = -1;
        while(menuItem != 0){
            menuItem = menu();
            switch (menuItem){
                case 1:
                    showTaskList();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    addTask();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    sortList();
                    break;
                case 0:
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid Input");

            }
        }
    }
    static int menu(){
        int choice;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\n Task List Menu \n");
        System.out.println("0: Exit Menu");
        System.out.println("1: Show Tasks in List");
        System.out.println("2: Add Task to List");
        System.out.println("3: Sort Tasks by Due Date");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Enter a choice: ");
            choice = sc.nextInt();
            return choice;
    }

    static void showTaskList(){
        System.out.println("\nTask List\n");
        try {
            Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));
            String line;
            int number = 1;
            while(inFile.hasNextLine()){
                line = inFile.nextLine();
                System.out.println(number + ". " + line);
                ++number;
            }
            System.out.println();
            inFile.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe);
        }
    }

    static void addTask(){
        System.out.println("\nAdd Task\n");
        try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileName, true));
            System.out.println("Enter a Task: ");
            String addedTask = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Set Due Date for this Task(yyyy-mm-dd): ");
            String dueDate = input.nextLine();
            outFile.println(addedTask + " " + dueDate);
            outFile.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe);
        }
    }
    static void sortList(){
        System.out.println("\nSorted List\n");

  }

}
```

Comment: Where is your sort method?

Comment: And where is your list? The addTask seems to just write to a file.

Comment: I added the rest of my code to the original post.  I'm hoping to add the collection.sort method in the sortList method.  I'm just not sure how to access the dueDate variable from the addTask method.

Comment: Real question is only "Could I use collection.sort for a date?" then

Comment: yes, but also how to access "dueDate" in the addTask method and use it in the sortTask method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Collections.sort().

However, you'll need to implement Comparable or Comparator to add in your own logic to sort it.

Try searching for comparable and comparator and you should see how to do it.

Comment: how would I reference the dueDate variable in the addTask method, though?

Comment: I think your issue is not having a proper "list" of Task POJO(plain old java object) defined. As you asked "how would I reference the dueDate", in the way you coded, your only option is pass back the dueDate but that will be only for one Task. What you need is a collection of Task POJO that you can pass around like a database. That way you can have access to all variable. 
Once you understand these concepts, I think you be able to come up with the solution.